# Base 64 encoding, Java or JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript

i've a particular js function that encrypts some form inputs into base64, but I need to run it in my Java app. So my question is, how can i call that function inside a java class? Otherwise I'll have to translate it but I think will be more complicated. Here's some of js code:

```
function encode64(input)
{
      //alert(input);
      //alert(input);
      input = escape(input);
      var output = "";
      var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
      var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
      var i = 0;

      var nMod =( input.length) % 3;
      //alert(nMod);
      //alert(input.length);
      do 
      {
         chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
         chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
         chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

         enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
         enc2 = (((chr1  << 4) | (chr2 >> 4))& 0x3f);
         enc3 = (((chr2  << 2) | (chr3 >> 6))& 0x3f);
         enc4 = chr3 & 0x3f;



         output = output + 
            keyStr.charAt(enc1) + 
            keyStr.charAt(enc2) + 
            keyStr.charAt(enc3) + 
            keyStr.charAt(enc4);
         chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
         enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
      } while (i < input.length);

    if(nMod == 1)
    {
        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        enc1 = ((chr1 & 192)>>2);
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) <<4);
        enc3 = "=";
        enc4 = "=";
        output = output + keyStr.charAt(enc1)
                + keyStr.charAt(enc2)
                + keyStr.charAt(enc3)
                + keyStr.charAt(enc4);
    }
    if(nMod == 2)
    {
        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        enc1 = ((chr1 & 192)>>2);
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4 )|((chr2 & 0xf0) >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) <<2);
        enc4 = "=";

        output = output + keyStr.charAt(enc1)
                + keyStr.charAt(enc2)
                + keyStr.charAt(enc3)
                + keyStr.charAt(enc4);
    }

      return output;
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: So you have a javascript function that you want to call from Java?  If thats the case, not likely to happen.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I've to get output string from this js in order to login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *but I think will be more complicated.*

Why would it be more complicated? You can perfectly do that in Java. If your actual problem is already the first line

```
input = escape(input);
```

then it's good to know that the Java equivalent is the `URLEncoder#encode()`. As to the remnant of the coding, it's ultimately straightforward. Just replace `var` by `String` or `char` here and there, align the methods according [`java.lang.String`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) API and you'll be fine.

**Edit**: for some downvoting nitpickers out here: I did NOT say that `URLEncoder#encode()` does the Base64 encoding. It just does URL encoding the same way as Javascript's `escape()` function does. That was just the first line of his to-be-translated Javascript code. Please *read* answers, do not *scan* answers.

Comment: So you insinuates that you thought that Javascript's `escape()` function equals to `Base64` thing? Reread it all dude.

Comment: it doesn't, of course.. but never mind.. I removed my downvote, to 'end the war'.. now you can perhaps remove yours from all my recent posts :P

Comment: (the point was that it is redundant to write all that code, and messing with URLEncode, while simply base64 was needed)

Comment: URLEncode.encode actually works as expected, I'm finishing the translation, worked ok with char and Strings, only have to be catch IndexOutOfBounds Exceptions when accesing charCodeAt(i++), thanks again BalusC!

Comment: You're welcome. The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s can be avoided by checking lengths properly.

Answer (score 3):

Or better use [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) 's [Base64 class](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html)

P.S. You do not "encrypt" into Base64 - you "encode"

Comment: sorry, english is not my native language

Comment: the native language doesn't matter - these are different terms.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that using a [javascript engine written in Java](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/), but I think it's better to simply translate it into java.

Answer (score 1):

I have used http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/ and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Translate the code into Java - it will be quicker. (Or search for an existing example in Java!)

Comment: Indeed I found some examples but not getting the same outputs :(

Comment: sscalzadona: could the different outputs be because your js implementation calls escape on the input? Why are you doing that, anyway?

Comment: Js code is implemented in an embedded device, I'd love to change that implementation, but I can't!